my admin password doesn't work after deleting the domain
I have a problem on my Windows Server 2016 server. I deleted the active directory domain by entering a password when deleting it, but after restarting, the administrator password does not work on the local session. I would like you to suggest a solution to resolve this problem without reinstalling the system.
